# What's the most reliable data compression algorithm for Android?

Tags: java, android, compression

I need an algorithm to compress my statistics data to minify bandwidth. It is in Android application, so I need an algorithm with low memory cost, minimum allocate count and the most reliable one. It looks like in some circumstances compression fails - OOM or quick process termination, I'm not sure.

I'm talking about gigabytes of data per day sent from hundreds of thousands of devices - each sends a small amount, but as soon as there are hundreds of thosands I constantly see some almost improbable errors.

Recently I used CBZip2InputStream, Deflater and GZIPOutputStream, I ended up with GZIPOutputStream because two previous sometimes gave data which can not be unpacked or just failed. But I'm not sure my choise is right, as I myself never saw all three fail in my local tests - only in server statistics I've received.

I do not need very high compression, at least some compression, but it must work everytime and ideally could use static data buffer that I provide. Maybe there is extremely low cost algorithm for that?

Please advise!

Comment: If you keep the information sent to less than the size of an ip packet, compression will just add overhead. You won't save bandwidth, and you'll just increase the overhead. One thing to consider is your network protocol. If the data is small, consider UDP.

Comment: "It looks like in some circumstances compression fails - OOM or quick process termination, I'm not sure" -- it is unlikely that those are due to a choice of compression algorithm. It is more likely that they are due to bugs in your own code that happens to use a compression algorithm.

Comment: @NomadMaker I have no choice and send it via TCP to php webservice. Regarding to size it could be between 1kb and 1Mb because it is sent by events and by filesize limit.

Comment: 1 MB is not what I'd refer to as "statistics". You also might reconsider your server software. Profiling that might increase your speed much more than improving your client.

Comment: @CommonsWare understand your point, but bugs here is not the case, compression part it is very simple code and it works in 100% my home tests. And the issue here it can't be unpacked on the other end. It may be caused by process termination, so the file is just didn't fully written. So I want to minimize this probability.

Comment: "It may be caused by process termination" -- and that's a bug in your code that happens to use a compression algorithm. "So I want to minimize this probability" -- then you need to fix the bug in your code that happens to use a compression algorithm. Changing the compression algorithm itself is unlikely to help.

Comment: @NomadMaker you could also suggest to change platform to windows 10, haha. I do understand that server side is inefficient, but I have what I have - php entry point and gigs of compressed data everyday, and some data is corrupted.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok, I get your point. Sadly process termination and OOM in android is not a bug in client code, but Android nature, problem could be in another process but system kills yours. Some algorithms like bz2 are slow and memory consuming so they just don't have enough time in onDestroy to finish work. Again we say about very rare situations, when app writes a file and on memory allocation inside compression lib here comes OOM. Or Mary occasionally calls to Ann while she played a game and Android decides it has too many processes. Maybe there is GZip with static buffer?

Comment: @NomadMaker by the way my part of server code is very efficient and very small, in fact I moved all processing to the third node - my stand alone server with MSSQL and c++ code, php server only stores some data in mysql without unpacking, so php is not a bottleneck here

Comment: "problem could be in another process but system kills yours" -- use a foreground service. Or, use `WorkManager` and use a retry policy if the work does not get done within the window. "and memory consuming" -- for the data that you are compressing, you should be compressing to a file (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`), then uploading the resulting file. "so they just don't have enough time in onDestroy to finish work" -- do not do anything significant in `onDestroy()` of any activity or service.

Comment: @CommonsWare in addition to call in main app I use JobIntentService, and before that I used WakefulIntentService that wrote someone called commonsware :) This service enqueueWork method is called in app onDestroy. Ok, I stay with Gzip. Thank you!

Comment: "in addition to call in main app I use JobIntentService" -- that is better than some options, but I would use `WorkManager`. In your case, you need to ensure that you have Internet access for the upload process, and `WorkManager` constraints let you specify that. Chained work, where you compress in one piece and upload in a second, constrained piece, is there for your use case. "before that I used WakefulIntentService that wrote someone called commonsware" -- while my intentions were noble, that code did not age well. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`.

Comment: But I would be focusing on stuff like what we have discussed in these past few comments, ensuring the reliability of the code doing the compression and the uploading, more so than worrying about the compression algorithm itself. A change in algorithm might have benefits (smaller/faster/etc.), but if you are using an existing implementation of that algorithm, reliability itself is unlikely to change.

Comment: @CommonsWare in fact before I compress a file there are several conditions and network is among them. Will look at WorkManager, thank you!

Comment: @CommonsWare well in highload c++ world I used to consider "new" as a bad idea, so I use preallocated or static memory just where I can. Java world is purely architectural and dynamic, classes on top of classes on top of classes. And very often I end up with static int arrays with my own management to make everything work each frame :) Thus I thought there is a java implementation of Gzip which will not allocate memory at all and work in buffer I gave.

Answer (score 0):

The data compression and decompression are not what is unreliable. You need to debug the unreliable data transfer or processing you are experiencing.

Comment: I may use not correct word, I meant algorithm that is simple, fast and can use preallocated memory buffer, and thus can work in "aggressive" and not reliable environment. Imagine static arrays in comparison with dynamic list of objects which in turn use "new" a lot.

Comment: @Tertium Then your question is asking about two entirely different things. One part of your question is looking for help to debug failures in your communication. You posit some possible causes such as "unreliable" compression and decompression or out of memory faults, but you actually have no idea. The second part of your question is asking for an approach that uses a static data buffer. You then need to ask two _different_ questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: Memory usage is highly unlikely to be causing your problem, unless there is an error in your code that is preventing the GZIPOutputStream from closing and releasing its resources. If it is releasing its resources properly, then its usage of memory is no different than if it were static. It just keeps allocating and freeing and allocating and freeing the same amount of memory that would have been reserved statically.

Comment: You can write your own class to do gzip compression with memory that is allocated only once, using zlib. (Which is what the Deflater and GZIPOutputStream classes are using.) zlib provide `deflateReset()` whose purpose is precisely to recycle the memory allocated by `deflatreInit()` for a new compression task, without freeing and allocating.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I'm probably hunting for ghosts. Asked just to make sure it is so. I suspect every particular "new" because when alloc is called, Android calls GC, and god knows what may happen :)

Comment: Just to be sure - should I try to decompress data immediatelly after I compressed it in java to make sure it worked? Or catching gzip exceptions is enough?

Comment: I suppose you could if you're especially paranoid, but there's really no point. The CRC will be checked on the other end.